# Seemingly inconsistent onstorage triggering in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I've encountered the following issue in the Safari 5.0 (not in all WebKit-based browsers), this code:

```
<html>                                                                                                   
<script>                                                                                             
    var onstorage = function(evt) {                                                                  
            alert([evt.key, evt.oldValue, evt.newValue].join('\n'));                                 
    }                                                                                                

    var onclick = function(evt) {                                                                    
        localStorage.setItem('test', Math.random());                                                 
    }                                                                                                

    var oninit = function() {                                                                        
      //actually, it works the same way with old "plain event" onclick                               
      document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', onclick, false);                     
      window.addEventListener('storage', onstorage, false);                                          
    }                                                                                                

</script>                                                                                            

<body onload="oninit()">                                                                             
    <input id="test" type="button" value="setting a random value"/>                                  
</body>
```

will trigger on alert, in case we click the button. While this code -

```
<html>                                                                                                   
<script>                                                                                             
    var onstorage = function(evt) {                                                                  
            alert([evt.key, evt.oldValue, evt.newValue].join('\n'));                                 
    }                                                                                                

    var onclick = function(evt) {                                                                    
        localStorage.setItem('test', Math.random());                                                 
    }                                                                                                

    var oninit = function() {                                                                                           
      window.addEventListener('storage', onstorage, false); 
       //actually, it works the same way with old "plain event" onclick                               
      document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', onclick, false);                                       
    }                                                                                                

</script>                                                                                            

<body onload="oninit()">                                                                             
    <input id="test" type="button" value="setting a random value"/>                                  
</body>
```

triggers few alerts, as not expected. 
I do think this is a bug, but can't somebody explain me - why swapping just two lines of codes results in such a weird behaviour?

Comment: Dunno, `onstorage` doesn't work for me. But in general you should avoid calling global variables/functions `onstorage` or `onclick`. Because `onclick` is accessible as `window.onclick`, it will receive click events for `window` even without `addEventHandler`!

Comment: bobince, silly me))) you are totally right - there are some problems  with onclick variable in global scope. Nonetheless, it is a bug, but less enigmatic )

Comment: How is it a bug when you are trying to use reserved global method names?

Comment: As well as the name clash with onclick, giving handler functions names that begin with 'on' confuses them with the actual event handlers like onclick and onload. I think it's better to give handlers names that describe what they're responding to or what they do, like 'handleClick' or 'initData'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug (although like others have commented I would not name the event handlers as global functions with names that might confuse).

The issue is how the notifications for localStorage work. In essence, events are only fired for *other* windows (or tabs) that use the same localStorage.

Here's [a similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679023/bug-with-chromes-localstorage-implementation) here on StackOverflow.

So, in your example, the storage changed event won't fire: the handler is on the same page.