# I am wondering if it is possible to send data between windows using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

My goal is to have the scenario as follows:

```
1) User opens myapp.com in Window A
2) User clicks button which opens myapp.com/doWork in Window B
3) After performing some operations and retrieving data (requiring user input), Window B closes
4) Window A displays the data retrieved from Window B
```

Is this possible using node.js? I realize that a simpler solution would be to simply have everything done in a single window. I am using express/handlebars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), which enables real-time communication between your Node.js server and all browser clients that have your webpage opened.

In your particular case, before the window B closes, the server should send a message to the client with the new data. The client-side code will then be able to update the webpage with the new information.

If you are looking for a barebone solution, check out the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) (which Socket.io abstracts). If you want to use a complete framework built for real-time applications, check out [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) (which will require more code modification, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

actually you don't need to do it on the server.
as far as i can see, both of your windows open on the same host/domain (including same port and subdomain)

this means both windows can "talk" to eachother on the client side.
windowB has the `window.opener` property for that.

so what ever happens in windowB, at any time you can tell windowA what happend, like this.

**in windowB**

```
window.opener.setData(myResult); // window.opener == windowA
```

or

```
window.opener.myGlobalNamespaceObject.property = myResult
```

another solution would be to use cookies, or localStorage for that.
Actually localStorage triggers an event, when data has been set (see this question: [localStorage eventHandler Doesn't Get Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428671/local-storage-events))

if you don't share the same domain go with socket.io as the other answer points out.

Comment: You've got a good answer that would be improved if you edited it to use proper upper casing for words and sentences.