# SessionStorage Binding Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Similar question from 
[How do I bind event to sessionStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260108/how-do-i-bind-event-to-sessionstorage)

Is there anyway to only bind the session storage only without binding the local one.

```
$(window).bind('storage', function(e)
{
    alert('change');
});
```

The code above seems to bind both storage (local and session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think binding an event exclusively to session storage changes is possible, but you could ignore events caused by changes in localStorage:

```
$(window).on('storage',function(e){
   if(e.originalEvent.storageArea===sessionStorage){
     alert('change');
   } 
   // else, event is caused by an update to localStorage, ignore it
});
```

PS: `on` is the preferred method for attaching event listeners with jQuery.